# Sony BTN200 bluetooth headphone on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth, headphones

I have a pair of SONY BTN200 bluetooth headphone that I would like to use on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Unfortunately my laptop cannot see them. Bluetooth is on on both the laptop and the headphone of course, but the laptop simply cannot see the headphone. I tried googling the issue but I couldn't find anything. Has anyone encountered any problem when connecting bluetooth headphones to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS? If yes, how did you fix it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

You have to turn off your headphones, and then hold the power button for about 6-7 seconds until the light starts blinking red and blue. Then your headphones will be visible for the laptop.